# game size on html

Tags: playn

I'm using the latest PlayN version from git, where it was removed the setSize(w, h) method from the platform.

On the Java backend I give my game the desired dimension with:

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.width = 720;
conf.height = 600;

JavaPlatform platform = JavaPlatform.register(conf);
```

I compile to HTML but now I'm not sure how to specify the game size on the HTML platform. I give the #playn-root element a style like this:

```
<style>
  #playn-root {
    height: 600px;
    width: 720px;
  }
</style>
```

And it *does* resize the div element, but my game it's still all shrinked inside of it (size 300 x 150)

Here's the init code for the game:

```
root = _iface.createRoot(new AbsoluteLayout(), rootSheet, graphics().rootLayer()).setSize(graphics().width(), graphics().height());
```

I'm missing something but I couldn't find what to change.

Comment: For folks who don't know, you do have to add a div ``<div id="playn-root"></div>`` to your body for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was a bug in PlayN (the OOO fork), it was fixed in https://github.com/threerings/playn/commit/058a2e6919131b39cf2c26eb3db3fb220e523879